# Limit number of selections to one in each field in shinyWidgets::selectizeGroupUI

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

I have 4 dependent selection fields realized with selectizeGroup functions. I would like to limit the number of choices to only one item in each field. Is it possible?

The code below works like a charm for multiple selections in each field. I would like to limit the selections so only picking one is possible. Where and what parameter to add if it exists?

Here is my working selectizeGroup application:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 10, offset = 1,
      tags$h3("Filter data with selectize group"),
      panel(
        selectizeGroupUI(
                         id = "my-filters",
                         inline = TRUE,
                         params = list(
                           p_lev5 = list(
                             inputId = "p_lev5",
                             title = "Level 5",
                             placeholder = 'select',
                             options = list(limit = 1)
                             

                           ),
                           p_min = list(
                             inputId = "p_min",
                             title = "Group minor",
                             placeholder = 'select'

                           ),
                           sm = list(
                             inputId = "sm",
                             title = "Manager",
                             placeholder = 'select'

                           ),
                           rp = list(
                             inputId = "rp",
                             title = "Representative",
                             placeholder = 'select'
                           )
                         ),
                         
                       ),
        status = "primary"
      ),
      plotOutput("plot1")
    )
  )
)
        

  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
 
    
    res_mod <- callModule(
      module = selectizeGroupServer,
      id = "my-filters",
      data = df_prc_ch_minor,
      vars = c("p_lev5", "p_min", "sm", "rp")
    )
    
    output$plot1 <-
      renderPlot({
        req( input[["my-filters-p_lev5"]],
             input[["my-filters-p_min"]],
             input[["my-filters-sm"]],
             input[["my-filters-rp"]])
        fn_plt_prcech(
          input[["my-filters-p_lev5"]],
          input[["my-filters-p_min"]],
          input[["my-filters-sm"]],
          input[["my-filters-rp"]])
      })
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The part `options = list(limit = 1)` is what I dream about, of course. Thank you for all the indications.

Comment: Looking for the same answer !